# Find the degree of $[\mathbb{Q}(\mu):\mathbb{Q}(\mu + \mu ^{-1})]$

Tags: galois-theory

Find the degree of [$\mathbb{Q}(\mu):\mathbb{Q}(\mu + \mu ^{-1})$]. Here $\mu$ is the primitive $nth$ root of 1.
I know for $n$ being a prime, [$\mathbb{Q}(\mu):\mathbb{Q}$]=n-1, but not sure about this case.

Answer (score 3):

As $\mu^2-(\mu+\mu^{-1})\mu+1=0$, we see that $\mu$ is a zero of the polynomial $X^2-(\mu+\mu^{-1})X+1\in\mathbb Q(\mu+\mu^{-1})[X]$.

Show that that polynomial is in fact the minimal polynomial of $\mu$ over $\mathbb Q(\mu+\mu^{-1})$.

Comment: Making, of course, an exception for $n=2$.